# Integer solutions to $\frac{d^3}{r}+r=a^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, cubics

> What are the positive integer solutions $(a,d,r)$ to $\frac{d^3}{r}+r=a^2$?

This is a revised version of my deleted question. Alternate forms are $d^3 = r(a^2-r)$ and from the quadratic formula $a^4-4d^3=b^2 \Rightarrow 4d^3 = a^4 - b^2=(a^2+b)(a^2-b)$, with $a,b$ the same parity.

Small solutions $(d, r, a)$: $(2,1,3), (72,36,102), (75,25,130), (92,8,312),(360,81,759)$

Comment: First of all, which variable are you solving for? Please be specific.

Comment: @Libertron integer solutions $(d, r)$ given $a$, alternatively integer solutions $(a, d, r)$

Comment: @Libertron modified original post so it is easier to understand

Comment: Hint: Start playing around a little with random positive integers. One possibility is $(3, 2, 1)$. I haven't dealt with Diophantine equations for quite some time now. Also, note that the LHS of your equation has got to be a perfect square!

Comment: @Libertron added some solutions

Comment: @StephenG: For your edit, are you sure that is the intent of the OP?

Comment: Words cut and pasted directly from the OP's comment in answer to @Libertron above.  I can only assume that's the intent.  OP can correct if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

This has an interesting connection to *Pell equations*. Let,

$$(a^2-r)r = d^3\tag1$$

then this has an infinite number of integer solutions given by,

$$d,r,a = \tfrac{n}{2}y^2;\;\tfrac{1}{4}y^2,\;\tfrac{1}{2}xy,\tag2$$

where,

$$x^2-2n^3y^2 = 1\tag3$$

Since for $n=1$ (and others) the $y$ are all even $y = 0, 2, 12, 70, 408, 2378, 13860,\dots$ as [A001542](https://oeis.org/A001542), then $(2)$ are all integers. Its smallest $d,r,a$ are,

$$2,\,1,\,3\\72,\,36,\,102$$

Of course, $(2)$ does not give all solutions, but easily shows there is an infinity of them.

Comment: What do you think of the difference of squares $4d^3=(a^2+b)(a^2-b)$?

Comment: @qwr: How did you transform $d^3 =r(a^2 −r)$ to $a^4 −4d^3 =b^2$?

Comment: Solving for $r$ using quadratic formula